# Get different numbers on a string separated by commas and put them in decimal variables

Tags: vb.net

The string str equals "59.161906499999986,60.2784931,0.0"

I have two other Decimal type variables, decimal1 and decimal2.

If str is "59.161906499999986,60.2784931,0.0" (of course quotations aren't there), the output should be:

```
decimal1 = 59.161906499999986
decimal2 = 60.2784931
```

Any way to do this?

Comment: [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) will do what you want. (I didn't downvote, but I suspect it was because the tiniest amount of research could have found this.)

Comment: I probably worded my search incorrectly, because I actually didn't find anything. Any way to get it on two different variables? I can use the array I get, but it would just be more convenient. Also, If I use that, there would be a third substring with 0.0, which I don't need.

Comment: Fair enough - I accept it's sometimes difficult to know just what to search for. Re your question, no just get it into the array and populate the variables you require from there. Don't worry about the array having an extra element.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Had been stuck there a few days

Answer (score 1):

There is a Linq way of doing it. To get a list of decimals from the string, you can use:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Linq

Public Class Program

  Public Shared Sub Main()
    Dim inputString As String = "59.161906499999986,60.2784931,0.0"
    Dim q =(From item In inputString.Split(","c) Select Double.Parse(item)).ToList()
    For Each item In q
        Console.WriteLine(item)
    Next
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Isn't using linq little bit trivial for this simple problem?

Comment: I, for one, am happy to see a simple example of linq. @Sunil I keep Option Strict on so is Dim q As List(Of Double) correct?

Comment: elegant solution +1. @mary, LINQ is strongly typed, the compiler will not tolerate    list that is not  List(Of Double) you are correct...